# Find the amount by which the debt increases due to a late payment involving compound interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Tony owes Peter R9000 due in twelve months from now, earning an interest rate of 15 % per annum compounded monthly
>
> Tony is unable to pay on the due date, and pays sixteen months from now. How much more will he pay?

My attempt:

$$S=P(1+i)^n
  =9000(1+0,15)^{16}
  =9000 \times 9.357620874
  =54218.58787 $$

Comment: Do you know the formula for compound interest?

Comment: Yes I do, I have tried it a few ways, however I'm not confident about my answer. I have it as a multiple choice question, and when I calculated it I got none of the above.

Comment: You should edit your question to show us your attempt, and maybe someone can find the mistake.

Comment: Options.  : 1) 10 979,01.     2) 9458,51.    3) 662,81.      4)458,51.        5) none of the above

Comment: It doesn't help us to know what options someone gave you.  That doesn't change the mathematical content of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The amount owed would have been $9000(1+r)^{12}$ where $r=\frac{0.15}{12}$.

Now it will be $9000(1+r)^{16}$. This number turns out to be the answer A. However, since the problem asks how much **more** will he pay, I do not consider that to be the correct answer. The actuall *difference* is about $532.22$.

Comment: Thanx So much :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You should divide the annual interest, 0.15, by 12 to get the monthly interest.

Comment: Thanx trevor, I will try it that way and let u know what I get.